# Quartz 3.06 not Executing Jobs from XML file

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I tried to execute this code.. but unfortunately code not running.. its working in older versions

```
    static async void QuartzInitializer()
    {
        try
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            // our properties that enable XML configuration plugin
            var properties = new NameValueCollection
            {
            ["quartz.plugin.triggHistory.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin, Quartz.Plugins",
            ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.type"] = "Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz.Plugins",
            ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames"] = "quartz_jobs.xml",
            ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound"] = "true",
            ["quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval"] = "60",

            };
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
            IScheduler sched = await sf.GetScheduler();
            await sched.Start();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Main();
        }
    }
```

No Exeception is thrown. I tried using try catch also.
its exiting at await sched.Start();

Comment: What does logging tell you?

Comment: It didn't gave me any messages or exception , debugging stopped without any error message after executing sched.Start();

Comment: When I downgrade the version to 2.60 its working fine.

Comment: You have installed the extra Plugins NuGet package? https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html

Comment: Yes i already did that before.

Comment: if you have any github repo about this please share me

Comment: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/src/Quartz.Examples/example15

Comment: can you verify this code? https://github.com/princebtq/QuartzWeb

Comment: same problem exists